contact form 7 Электронный адрес отправителя не принадлежит домену сайта
Подскажите пожалуйста какой у меня адресс электронной почты если у меня сайт на локальном сервере open server называется startcar 
менял по разному и так [_site_title] wordpress@startcar wordpress@startcar и вводил свою почту без результата

на локальном можешь забить на это. Всё равно почта не нужна и тестировать её бесполезно. Но вне зависимости от этого нужно даже на локальном делать нормальные адреса сайтов. Пусть фейковые, но соответствующие стандартам.

Используйте электронный адрес, принадлежащий домену сайта
Убедитесь, что электронный адрес, указанный в поле "From" (От), принадлежит домену вашего сайта. Например, если ваш сайт находится на домене example.com, то электронный адрес должен быть something@example.com
это должно работать даже если фактически этот адрес не создан, а только установлен и настроен email server с возможностью добаения алиасов. Сейчас у всех хостингов это по умолчанию сделано
